# Need help to run gwmi in a series of servers

Tags: powershell

i need help to make a script work to run this command.

```
gwmi win32_product -Filter {Name like "%softwarex%"} -ComputerName server1
```

I choose gwmi because i dont have permissions to run cmdlets like invoke. I need to find in which of a list of servers a software is installed and have a report.

Thank you

Comment: `-ComputerName server1, server2, server3`... it accepts an array.

Comment: whats wrong with what you got? what errors do you have?

Comment: `Win32_Product` only lists programs installed via Windows Installer. I wrote a script a while back that collects installed software on computers. The article explains how to use it. [IT Pro - Auditing 32-bit and 64-bit applications in PowerShell](http://beta.itprotoday.com/scripting/auditing-32-bit-and-64-bit-applications-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiable ways of doing it
@() means array.

```
@("server1","Server2","Server3") | %{gwmi win32_product -Filter {Name like "%softwarex%"} -ComputerName $_ }
```

If your doing it by text file (Line by Line)

```
Get-Content C:\test.txt | %{gwmi win32_product -Filter {Name like "%softwarex%"} -ComputerName $_
```

If you want to do it by a function

```
Function Get-Win32Product([string]$ServerName){
    gwmi win32_product -Filter {Name like "%softwarex%"} -ComputerName $ServerName
}
Get-Win32Product -ServerName Sever1
```